# What does "ict" mean in output in python?

Tags: python-3.x, output

I made up this example to go over basic dictionary skills and I expected a number output but instead, I get this strange out put of `"ict"` when I run it. Any help is appreciated.

```
dictionary:{
  1:4.03,
  2:3435.4,
  3:65.2,
}
print("dictionary"[1]+"dictionary"[2]+"dictionary"[3])
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `"dictionary"` is not `dictionary`.

Answer (score 1):

```
"dictionary"[1] == 'i'
"dictionary"[2] == 'c'
"dictionary"[3] == 't'
```

That's because `"dictionary"` is a string, not your variable called `dictionary`.